# Issue with custom report

Tags: magento-1, grid, reports

I have created a custom report with custom collection. The issue is that I am getting an extra row in report grid. Please check screen shot to get a better idea.
[image]

Check my code below for one of the columns. Is there any property missing that would hide that row?

`Grid.php`

```
$this->addColumn('customer_lastname', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Last Name'),
    'index' => 'customer_lastname',
    'sortable'      => false,
    'filter' => false,
));
```

I also want to remove "Reset Filter" and "Search" button. So please help me for that also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you grid block, in the constructor or `_prepareLayout` method, add this line.

```
$this->setFilterVisibility(false);
```

If you are adding it in the constructor, add it after `parent::__construct`.

Comment: If you check screenshot you will find that no. of "Total Records found" is 1. Instead 3. Do you know where I am wrong ?  Actually I am joining 2 tables. One of them have multiple entry of single order so I have to consider that only once.

Comment: @Krupali. This is a totally different issue. You should ask an other question and post as much code as possible from your module.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exactly row, that is the place where you could find the filter in order to filter out the rows as per your wish.

```
$this->addColumn('customer_lastname', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Last Name'),
'index' => 'customer_lastname',
'sortable'      => false,
'filter' => true,
));
```

In the filter, if you use 'true', you will find the filter.

For removing reset filter use , $this->setFilterVisibility(false);